# FQL Multiquery Returned Info

Tags: facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I'm trying to use an FQL Multiquery to obtain my most recent Facebook question and options with one query using an http request.

So far the query I tried to use is:

```
SELECT name, votes FROM question_option WHERE question_id IN 
   (SELECT id, question FROM question WHERE owner = me() 
   ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Unfortunately this only returns the name and votes from the outer query and not the question text from the inner one. Is there a way to retrieve all 3 without making 2 queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you posted isn't a multiquery. A proper multiquery should get you what you want:

```
{
'question_detail':
  'SELECT id, question FROM question WHERE owner = me() 
     ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 1',
'question_answers':
   'SELECT name, votes FROM question_option WHERE question_id IN
      (SELECT id FROM #question_detail)'
 }
```

You'll need to get rid of the whitespace for this to properly execute.

Comment: I'm making an HTTP request using just a URL, how would a multiquery like this translate to a valid URL?

Comment: It's pretty well explained in the facebook developer guides [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/#multi). Your query URL is like: `https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q={"question_detail":"SELECT+id,+question+FROM+question+WHERE+owner=me()+ORDER+BY+created_time+DESC+LIMIT+1","question_answers":"SELECT+name,+votes+FROM+question_option+WHERE+question_id+IN+(SELECT+id+FROM+#question_detail)"}`

Comment: Yes I tried something very similar to that when I first tried a multiquery, unfortunately with the same result as your example.
`Parser error: unexpected '{' at position 0.`

Comment: Yet strangely if I rewrite the #question_detail as the original query it works fine, so thank you.

Comment: You've got to really watch the syntax here. The Facebook JSON parser is not forgiving at all. One small mistake and you'll get the `Unexpected {` error.