# My FQL queries stopped working for no reason.. is there any solution?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I've a very strange problem with Facebook Query Language!
Since 2-3 weeks ago my FQL Graph Api queries stopped working for no reason on FB Developer! They are PERFECTLY worked earlier!

Even as simple one as this:
fql?q={"eid":"SELECT eid FROM event WHERE creator=me()"}

"error": { "message": "(#601) Parser error: unexpected '{' at position 0.", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 601

{ and } no longer supported from now on?? Is there any solution?
**Thanks in advance!**

You can test the query here if you want:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: I'm using the above query in a multiquery solution thats why I need the "eid" results..
Example codes for multiquery can be found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389046/fql-multiquery-returned-info
This one is also not working anymore because of { and }

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they are stricter now about correctly URL-encoded data.

If you URL-encode your query to `%7B%22eid%22%3A%22SELECT+eid+FROM+event+WHERE+creator%3Dme%28%29%22%7D`, it works: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3D%257B%2522eid%2522%253A%2522SELECT%2Beid%2BFROM%2Bevent%2BWHERE%2Bcreator%253Dme%2528%2529%2522%257D

Comment: Wow! Thanks!
thats sick... How do "URL-encode" these queries Is there any "converter" for this?

Comment: There’s online tools for this of course, f.e. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ And most web-related programming languages offer something for this as well, PHP has it’s [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and JS has [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: Okay, thanks. Is there anything you can do if your query is a "bit" longer than the above example?

Comment: You should do the same thing, URL-encode it. Why are you asking, are you running into problems with longer queries?

Comment: Unfortunately, Yes. When you URL-encode, hm lets say 3000 character long queries then the encoder makes 4000-5000 long URLs from them, which is impossible to even copy-paste into browser :(
Isn't there any other solution to this problem, maybe they just changed some semantics in the Graph Api?